# Do you use "ce dont" or "dont" to complete this sentence?

Tags: pronoms, pronoms-relatifs

*Paw-Paw est un ancien combattant, ______ Tex est très fier.*

In the blank in the sentence above,I put **dont** as my answer. But apparently, the correct answer was **ce dont**. However, this doesn't make sense to me because the sentence is translated as:

*Paw-Paw is a veteran, **of whom** Tex is very proud.*

And "ce dont" would change the meaning of the sentence to:

*Paw-Paw is a veteran, **of what** Tex is very proud.*

which is wrong.

Am I mistaken or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: "of what" is wrong, but "ce dont" translates to "of which", which is'nt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use both, as both are correct. Tex can be proud **of Paw-Paw** or **of the fact that Paw-Paw is a veteran** in french as well as in english.

Now, the comma make me think the probability of the second choice is more likely because it separate "The fact that Paw-Paw is a veteran" from the second part of the sentence. But then one could ask : Why is Tex proud of the accomplishement of someone else ? Honestly, these are considerations outside of the understanding of "ce dont" and "dont", and you'd need to have some context or the will to split hairs to settle this.

Answer (score 2):

Well you are right everywhere, nothing wrong ! Except that the meaning of the sentence is supposed to be

> Paw-Paw is a veteran, of what Tex is very proud

"dont" actually refers to the fact that Paw-Paw is a veteran; but I agree there is an ambiguity.